# javascript: always pass the nth argument in a function as fixed value by default

Tags: javascript, lodash

the function takes 3 parameters like

```
function p(x,y,z){
 console.log(arguments);
}
```

so when we call it like
p(12,21,32)

a fourth argument should pass as say 56

so effectively the call should be p(12,21,32,56)

How to do this?

Condition We cannot change the function definition. I need to partially bind the fourth argument as 56 something like

p=p.bind(this,'','','',56);
 or use lodash

and then call p later like

p(12,21,32);

such that 56 should pass by default

Comment: you can always define function with 4 arguments, and whether or not to  pass the forth argument when call the method is up to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`_.partialRight()`](https://lodash.com/docs#partialRight) to create a new function that appends arguments to the end of the original function:

```js
function p(a, b, c)
{
  alert([].join.call(arguments, ','));
}

p = _.partialRight(p, 56);
p(1,2,3); // 1,2,3,56
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lodash/lodash/3.9.3/lodash.js"></script>
```

To exactly specify the position of the extra argument(s) you can use placeholders:

```
p = _.partialRight(p, _, _, _, _, _, _, 56); // add 56 as 7th arg
p(1,2,3); // 1,2,3,,,,56
```

Comment: but normal javascript closure is still better in the situation when I need to add 56 as 7th argument(say). Can we do that with any readymade lodash function?

Comment: Good solution and using lodash is fine, but there was some missed pedagogical opportunity here about higher-order functions etc. I think.

Comment: p = _.curryRight(p);
p = p( _ , _ , _ , _ , _ , _ ,56);
p(1,2,3); This will work for that :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
p = (function() {
    var old_p = p;
    return function(a, b, c) {
        return old_p(a, b, c, 56);
    };
})();
```

We remember the old version of `p` under the name `old_p` so we can invoke it even after we've redefined `p`. We do this inside the IIFE so that `old_p` does not pollute the global scope. Then, we return a function (which is assigned to `p`) which returns the result of calling `old_p` with the extra argument.

We can make this more general, to create "bound" functions which add extra arguments to any function call. Below I use ES6 syntax, especially the spread `...` operator. However, you can accomplish the same thing by manipulating the `arguments` object and using `apply`:

```
function bind_with_arguments_at_end(f, ...extra_args) {
    return function(...args) {
        return f(...args, ...extra_args);
    }
}
```

Where the function involved is a method on an object, it makes sense to "pass through" this, so the new function can be called as `this.bound_func` and things continue to work. Do do this, we can use `call`:

```
function bind_with_arguments_at_end(f, ...extra_args) {
    return function(...args) {
        return f.call(this, ...args, ...extra_args);
               ^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new function which uses [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to redirect its arguments to the original one, but using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to overwrite some of them:

```js
function fixArguments(f, args) {
  return function() {
    return f.apply(this, Object.assign([].slice.call(arguments), args));
  };
}
p = fixArguments(p, {3: 56}); // Overwrite the 4th argument with 56
```

```js
function fixArguments(f, args) {
  return function() {
    return f.apply(this, Object.assign([].slice.call(arguments), args));
  };
}
function p(x,y,z){
  console.log(arguments);
}
p = fixArguments(p, {3: 56});
p(12,21,32);
```

Comment: Like the weird-looking way to append args to something.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the original and override the name, and call the original with the new arguments.

```js
function p(a,b,c,d) {
   console.log(arguments);
}

(function (){
    var org_p = p;  //copy original
    p = function() {  //override p
        var args = [].slice.call( arguments );  //turn arguments in to array
        args.push(56);  //add the 4th argument
        return org_p.apply( this, args );  //call the original with the updated arguments.
    }
}());

p(1,2,3);
```